# Makefile relinking

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, multiple-makefiles

I am doing a school project, my makefile is always relinking and I can't figure out why.
I need to compile the objs with a library (libft that will have a libft.a file, so I need to create the library using other makefile). Also what are the best resources to learn makefile?

```
SRCS = src/pipex.c \
       src/utils.c \

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

NAME = pipex
LIBFT       = libft.a
LIBFT_DIR := ./libft
LIBFT_LIB := $(LIBFT_DIR)/$(LIBFT)
CC = cc
FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LIBC = ar rc
RM = rm -f

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS) $(LIBFT)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_LIB) -o $(NAME)

debug: $(OBJS) $(LIBFT)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -g $(SRCS) $(LIBFT_LIB) -o $(NAME)
    
$(LIBFT):
    @cd $(LIBFT_DIR) && $(MAKE) --silent

clean:
    cd $(LIBFT_DIR) && $(MAKE) clean
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BNS_OBJS)

fclean: clean
    cd $(LIBFT_DIR) && $(MAKE) fclean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: $(LIBFT)
```

I have tried to change the libft command to silent so no output to the screen and change the OBJS to the SRCS in $(NAME) command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure you want the standard and debug versions of the executable to have the same name?

Comment: Could happen if `libft.a` timestamp changes every time.

Comment: @Beta Yes, there is no problem if they have the same name, is just for me to test.

Comment: @AlexCohn I was testing and removed the execution of $(LIBFT) in $(NAME) and executed with libft.a, and no "relink" (since the timestamp changed its considered a relink?)

Comment: Yes, change of timestamp of `libft.a` file is designed to cause relink. This can be fixed within your `libft/Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a confusion of `libft.a` with `./libft/libft.a`.

Look at this rule:

```
$(LIBFT):
    @cd $(LIBFT_DIR) && $(MAKE) --silent
```

The target is `libft.a`, but it doesn't actually build `libft.a`, it builds `./libft/libft.a`. *Nothing* builds `libft.a` (in the working directory), but the `pipex` and `debug` rules have it as a prerequisite. So every time you tell Make to build one of those targets, Make sees that `libft.a` does not exist, so it tries to build it and then relink everything.

The fix is simple: give things accurate names:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_LIB)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_LIB) -o $(NAME)

debug: $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_LIB)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -g $(SRCS) $(LIBFT_LIB) -o $(NAME)
```

Comment: It worked, just had to change the $(LIBFT): to $(LIBFT_LIB):.